# NSComboBox binding not working in view-based NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nstableview

I have two NSArrayControllers, I'm using one to populate the information ina tableView and another to create a list of subjects which can be edited elsewhere in the app. I have a NSComboBox which I use to assign and save these subjects to the list in the tableView and it works fine if the ComboBox is cell-based. However, I want it to be view-based and for some bizarre reason the bindings refuse to work no matter how hard I try. Below is an image of my bindings. The "value" is working fine, however the drop down list (content bindings) simply won't populate with the subjects. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Second one binding might be wrong, you unbind that,where you have bound Content values

Subject--->arrangedObjects--->subjectName,

Now it will populate subject's list

Comment: I'm afraid that's not it. I can get it to work when it's not in the NSTableView, but inside, nothing. Thanks though.

Comment: Did you find out how to do it ? I'm facing the same problem and would like to sort it all out. Thank you.